# how get value of JSON object within Json ..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, couchdb

Please Help

```
"_attachments": {
       "kiran.jpg": {
           "content_type": "image/jpeg",
           "revpos": 6,
           "digest": "md5-mEsoX4ljN1iJlF2bX1Lw2g==",
           "length": 4601,
           "stub": true
       }
   }
```

I want to value of content_type and length.
how to get that.
friends i dont know the value of kiran.jpg, its come random image name form database

Comment: If it's still a string, parse the JSON into an object first. If it's an object already, `_attachments['kiran.jpg'].content_type` like any other object.

Comment: but i'm get runtime this object then, i don't know the name like.(kiran.jpg).

Comment: ["_attachments"]["kiran.jpg"].content_type

Comment: any another way for that

Comment: `var attachmentNames = Object.keys(data._attachments);` etc

Comment: i get only $data.row[0].value. _attachment;

Comment: In that i only get keys i want value of that keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use object.keys to loop over the keys in the _attachments object to find the name of each record.

```
var data = {
    "_attachments": {
       "kiran.jpg": {
           "content_type": "image/jpeg",
           "revpos": 6,
           "digest": "md5-mEsoX4ljN1iJlF2bX1Lw2g==",
           "length": 4601,
           "stub": true
       },
       "otherPerson.jpg" : {
           "content_type": "image/jpeg",
           "revpos": 8,
           "digest": "md5-mE4ljdfhgfh1iJlF2bX1Lw2g==",
           "length": 1337,
           "stub": false       
       }
   }
};

Object.keys(data._attachments).forEach(function( name ) {
    var contentType = data._attachments[name].content_type;
    console.log(contentType);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
var data = { 
   "_attachments": {
       "kiran.jpg": {
           "content_type": "image/jpeg",
           "revpos": 6,
           "digest": "md5-mEsoX4ljN1iJlF2bX1Lw2g==",
           "length": 4601,
           "stub": true
       }
   }
};
```

Then you can access the variables within like so:

```
var contentType = data["_attachments"]["kiran.jpg"].content_type
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming data is your object returned

```
data["_attachments"]["kiran.jpg"]["content_type"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data._attachments["kiran.jpg"].content_type ;
```

However , You said that `kiran.jpg` came randomly . Thus , you need to loop on attributes of `_attachments` :

```
 function getContentType(){

      for(var attr in data._attachments){
         return data._attachments[attr].content_type; 
         // break loop by return because `kiran.jpg ` is the first & only attribute
       }

  }
```